# Unable to unlock/turn on Nexus 4 : Lollipop 5.0.1

Tags: nexus-4, 5.0-lollipop, reboot

I am running Android 5.0.1 on my Nexus 4. This has started happening recently. Whenever my phone is locked, and I try to unlock, nothing happens on pressing the power button. Initially I thought my battery was getting drained to zero and phone was shutting down, but that's not the case. I need to long press power button and restart my phone forcefully. Some observations are:

- This issue was not there when I was on 5.0.0.
- Also I am finding that this is happening when I play a game and then close the game and leave the phone. Most recently, I have been playing [Swish](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.devionix.swish&hl=en) and [Drift Zone](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ai.driftzone&hl=en).
- However, even after uninstalling the issue persists.

Any suggestions/references to overcome this issue are welcome. TIA.

Comment: I have the same problem with 5.0.0 on a Nexus 4. It crashed once in the middle of the night and once when the alarm was supposed to ring. So it's not related to a game for me.

Comment: Coincidentally, I have been a victim of the exactly similar situation :)

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced many problems with Android 5 on both *my* Nexus 4 and my wife's exactly identical Nexus 4. Strangely enough, both phones experienced slightly different problems. The main issue with my own phone was WiFi - it simply did not work except for a few hour period after rebooting.

I have not experienced this issue since switching to Cyanogenmod using the instructions from their Wiki:

http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Install_CM_for_mako

My wife's phone has experienced the same exact problem as you. Sometimes it won't show anything on the screen, won't wake up. After rebooting everything is fine. This occurs even when plugged in and fully 100% recharged.

So my solution is to get away from Android 5 Lollipop. I don't know how to downgrade to an older version of Android, but moving to Cyanogenmod has fixed my own phone and I will be switching my wife over probably this evening.